# convert seconds to x days, hh:mm:ss in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working on a dataset that contains information about trips with start dates and end dates as timestamp. I am calculating the duration of these trips with:

```
SELECT
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, SECOND) AS ride_len_sec
FROM dataset.data
```

However this shows only the number of seconds. How can I display this in "x days, hh:mm:ss" format?

I've tried:

```
SELECT 
  ride_len_sec,
  ride_len_sec/3600 AS Hours,
  (mod(ride_len_sec,3600))/60 AS Minutes,
  mod(ride_len_sec,60) AS Seconds
FROM(
SELECT ride_id, started_at, ended_at, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, SECOND) AS ride_len_sec
  FROM dataset.data
)
```

but this shows hours and minutes in decimal points: ride_len_sec = 2100, Hours = 0.58333333333333337, Minutes = 35.0, Seconds = 0. Whereas my preferred output would be "0 days, 00:35:00"

---

Thanks for your replies. I tried converting to integer value by using
`CAST() AS int`
but this made '0.58333...Hours' into '1 Hours'.

I had looked into the time function, but it seems this cannot be used for cases when duration is more than 24hrs?

For the MAKE_INTERVAL function, I used:

```
SELECT
ride_len_sec,
MAKE_INTERVAL(second => ride_len_sec) AS Duration
FROM(
SELECT ride_id, started_at, ended_at, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, SECOND) AS ride_len_sec
  FROM `dataset.data`
```

However this yields in a different format with extra zeros for year-month:
ride_len_sec = 2100, Duration = 0-0 0 0:35:0. Is there any way to remove these from the output?

Comment: The result of calculation of: hours, minutes and seconds should be converted into integer value :)

Comment: Look at the time function for big query. You could use time_add, format_time or parse_time. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions

Comment: What about [MAKE_INTERVAL function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/interval_functions): `MAKE_INTERVAL(second=>ride_len_sec)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I display this in "x days, hh:mm:ss" format?

You can consider below.

```sql
WITH `dataset.data` AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([2100, 86400 + 2100, 3600000, 25000000]) ride_len_sec 
)
SELECT ride_len_sec, 
       FORMAT(
         '%d Days, %t',
         DIV(ride_len_sec, 86400), -- 24 hr * 60 min * 60 sec = 86400
         TIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(MOD(ride_len_sec, 86400)))
       ) Duration
  FROM `dataset.data`
```

or, with `INTERVAL` data type

```sql
WITH `dataset.data` AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([2100, 86400 + 2100, 3600000, 25000000]) ride_len_sec 
),
normalization AS (
  SELECT ride_len_sec,
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Duration) * 360 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Duration) * 30 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM Duration) AS days,
         EXTRACT(HOUR FROM Duration) AS hour,
         EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM Duration) AS minute,
         EXTRACT(SECOND FROM Duration) AS second
    FROM (
      SELECT ride_len_sec, JUSTIFY_INTERVAL(MAKE_INTERVAL(second => ride_len_sec)) Duration
        FROM `dataset.data`
    )
)
SELECT ride_len_sec, FORMAT('%d Days, %02d:%02d:%02d', days, hour, minute, second) duration 
  FROM normalization;
```

**Query results**

[image]

- See also

  - [How to get 10,000 years (max) interval in days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73696409/how-to-get-10-000-years-max-interval-in-days/73697204#73697204)
  - [JUSTIFY_INTERVAL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/interval_functions#justify_interval)